# ¿Cómo hacer un CRUD en un solo archivo ASP Clasico?

Tags: sql-server, asp

Estoy realizando un CRUD, pero fue creado en partes, es decir tengo un archivo ASP llamado leer datos, este archivo tiene la consulta de leer todos los datos de una table, así mismo tengo otro archivo ASP para dar de alta, pero lo que quiero es poner este código en un mismo archivo, no he llegado al objetivo ya que al momento de juntar los dos códigos, me manda en la pantalla index.asp que 192.168.1.75 te redireccionó demasiadas veces.

este es mi código junto, por podrían orientas como lo podría hacer por favor.

```
<!-- #include file="connection.asp" -->     

<%
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM pacientes"
    set ObjRst = Con.execute(strSQL)
  
%>

<%
    id_paciente = request.form("id_paciente")
    nombre = request.form("nombre")
    apellido = request.form("apellido")
    correo = request.form("correo")
    motivo = request.form("motivo")

    if (trim(id_paciente) = "") or (isnull(id_paciente)) then id_paciente = 0 end if

if cint(id_paciente) = 0 then

    strSQL = "insert into pacientes (nombre, apellido, correo, motivo) values('"&nombre&"', '"&apellido&"', '"&correo&"', '"&motivo&"');"
    Con.execute(strSQL)
    response.redirect("index.asp")
    
else
    strSQL = "UPDATE pacientes SET nombre = '"&nombre&"', apellido = '"&apellido&"',  correo = '"&correo&"',  motivo = '"&motivo&"' WHERE id_paciente = " & id_paciente
    Con.execute(strSQL)
    response.redirect("index.asp")
    response.End
end if
%>
```

Comment: Usa procedimientos almacenados.